# Incrementar numeros y no mostrar algunos numeros

Tags: c#

Quiero hacer un programa en C# que se incrementen números del 1 al 10 y no mostrar cuando es 2, 5 y 9. No se como hacerlo en C#

```
//Incrementar un numero de 1 a 10 y no mostrar cuando es 2,5 y 9
int num;
for(int x=1;x<=10;x++)
{
    if(x==7)
    {

     }
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo, necesito ayuda, no se como seguir.

Lo que yo hice fue declarar una variable que es num pensando que ahi tenia que guardar los numeros que no queria que se muestren. Luego, use el if para decir que si x==7 no se muestre, pero no se como seguir desarrollando para imprimir los numeros del 1 al 10 en la consola, y que no se muestren esos numeros. Ese es mi problema

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: No está muy claro lo que preguntas. Tienes un bucle de 1 a 10, pero para que quieres `num`? Puedes pulsar en [edit] y aclararlo un poco?

Comment: Podrias dejar bien en claro cual es el problema que tenes? porque un simple if no soluciona tu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hace el código es declarar una variable x local al bucle for, que en cada iteracion compara si es 2, 5 o 9, si cumple la condición mostrará un mensaje de que no ha podido sacarse el numero, si no cumple la condicion mostrará el número por el cual vaya la iteracion del bucle for proseguirá con la siguiente iteración.

```
for(int x=1;x<=10;x++)
{
     if(x==2 || x==5 || x==9)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("No se ha podido mostrar el numero");
     }
     else 
     {
          Console.WriteLine(x);
     }
}
```

Comment: Exacto, me gustaria que me expliques bien. Porque lo que quiero hacer es que no se muestren, pero que los demas si se muestren. Como hago?

Comment: Okey eso lo entendi, ahora bien quiero que en el if se pueda mostrar un mensaje o algo de que esos numeros que ingreso no se pueden mostrar, se que es con Console.WriteLine, pero como se hace?

Comment: Soy nuevo en este tema, perdon por mis preguntas estupidas pero necesito ayuda

Comment: Ahi lo tienes aplicado a tu duda

Comment: Y ahora como hago para mostrar solo los numeros impares?

Comment: Para los numeros impares debes meter otro condicional tal que:

if((x%2) != 0) Console.WriteLine("El numero es impar")

Con esto lo que te dice es si el resto al dividir por 2 no es 0 significa que es impar, con lo cual te saca ese mensaje.
Ponlo justo debajo del else, ya que es una condicion distinta a la evaluada anteriormente, pero siempre dentro del for.

Comment: Y si quiero mostrar cuando es par seria if((x*2). Seria asi?

Comment: noen vez de != 0 seria == 0